# How to make an efficient check constraint for an e-mail field in Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

How to make an efficient check constraint for an e-mail field in Firebird (if field value not null)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [SIMILAR TO](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-similar-to.html) operator to test against regular expression pattern, something like

```
CHECK(emailfield SIMILAR TO '[[:ALNUM:]._%+-]+@[[:ALNUM:].-]+\.[[:ALPHA:]]+')
```

Comment: Though it's very close, it's also going to match i.e. foo@bar..com and that's not valid email address. Also foo.@bar.com is invalid and still matched.

Comment: Yes, the pattern I gave is not perfect, perhaps should have spelled it out more clearly than "something like". The perfect pattern is too complex to list here, I just wanted to show the basic idea.

Comment: The only real validation of an emailaddress is sending a confirmation message :) I am usually annoyed when entirely valid emailaddresses are rejected because people didn't validate according to the RFC (which is almost impossible using a regex).

Answer (score 3):

IMHO this kind of validation should take place in the application code, and not in the database. Anyway, the suggestion approach with a regular expression seems nice !

Comment: Thanks, eventually I followed an advice I found elsewhere to only check the basic elements in an email address to avoid problems in exceptional cases, so I use VALUE like '_%@_%._%'

Comment: +1 because generally, the user input should be validated by the business application logic. The database should manages only data and apply business logic to them. Using the database as "data validator" isn't a good pratice.

Comment: Validations should be in both place. In the database to protect your DB (thick database concept) And in business logic to for a good user experience